# Timber:get_posts() with orderby meta_value sorting by post type

Tags: custom-post-type, timber

I am trying to get a collection of 2 different post types sorted by their start date. The two custom post types are just about identical in structure. They both have a `message_date` property. When I tried to get them and sort by the `message_date`, it sorts them first by `post_type` and then by `message_date`. Here's the code:

```
$message_args = array(
  'post_type' => array('message', 'podcast'),
  'orderby' => array('meta_value' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'ASC'),
  'meta_key' => 'message_date',
);
$messages = Timber::get_posts( $message_args );
```

I have double checked the formatting of the values and they are all `yyyymmdd`. I've tried it without sorting by `post_type` as well and I get the same result. Is there an easy way to override this?

Comment: Is there a difference when you run a normal `WP_Query`, like this: `$messages = new WP_Query( $message_args )`?

Comment: The only solution I could find to this was to run the results through a custom sorting function afterwards.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution. It may be even faster than adapting the query to make it work.